# How can I outer join two unnamed columns of two different files in python

Tags: python, pandas, join, outer-join

I have two files File 1 and 2. I want to perform outer join on first column of both of them. But, the problem is that both of the files have *unnamed* columns.

So, is there any way I can apply outer join on *unnamed* columns?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

**File 1:**

```
0    6    7
1    4    9
2    0    3
3    5    8
```

**File 2:**

```
0    7    3
1    3    9
2    6    2
3    8    0
```

**Expected Output:**

```
0    6    7    7    3
1    4    9    3    9
2    0    3    6    2
3    5    8    8    0
```

Comment: Is this actually about pandas?

Comment: Yes, pandas. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: @Dhruvil21_04, are you are asking about `outer join` or about horizontal concatenation?

Comment: I exactly want what I mentioned in expected output. I'm not sure about concatenation or outer join which one is correct.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to concatenate your files horizontally:

```
d1 = pd.read_csv(filename1, header=None)
d2 = pd.read_csv(filename1, header=None)

pd.concat([d1, d2], axis=1).to_csv(r'/path/to/result.csv', index=False)
```

PS you may want to specify a correct separator `sep='???'` (default is `sep=','`) when calling `pd.read_csv()` and `.to_csv()`